# Behavior of $f(x)=(-1)^x$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

> For what $x$ is $f(x)=(-1)^x$ a real number, and when is it a complex number?

When I graph it online, the graph glitches out and has points all over the place.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = e^{i \pi x}$

Comment: Remember, $(-1) = e^{i \pi}$

Comment: The first thing one should ask, maybe, is the **definition** of the expression $(-1)^x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same as $\exp(x\pi i)=\cos(x\pi)+i\sin(x\pi)$. For it to be real, $\sin(x\pi)=0$, i.e. $x$ is an integer.

Comment: That does make sense. The only thing $(-1)^\frac{2}{3}=((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{3}=1$, where is the fallacy in that equation?

Comment: @Simplex1 when dealing with complex numbers, numbers can have more than $1$ root. I gave the formula for the **principal** root, but there are more, given by integer multiples of the argument. Your equation neglects that, and only looks at the real one.

Answer (score 1):

If you recall that $(-1) = e^{i \pi}$ then $$f(x)= e^{i \pi x}$$
Which is then $$\cos(\pi x) +i\sin(\pi x)$$

Does this help at all?

Answer (score 1):

When $-1$ is raised to power of $x$ the complex number so formed has a real part $\cos \pi x $  and imaginary part  $\sin \pi x.$ This can be found using Euler formula $ e^{i \pi}=-1$. The two parts are graphed below .. with each part having a period or wave length  $\lambda=2, $ the roots are at $x=..,-2,-1,0,1,2,...$ etc.

Real part vanishes for all integer values of $x$ as is obvious from graph and direct check by plugin.

The $f(x)$ thus is always complex for all real values of $x$

Again for complex $x= a+ib ,\, f(x) $ is complex.

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, but while I agree the phrasing in the question is vague, I think "complex" is supposed to mean "complex and not real" in the question. So even though it's correct that $f(x)$ is always complex, I think this doesn't directly answer the OP's question.

Comment: I understood OP question as asking: [when is $f(x) $ real and when is it complex?]